Can Flutter support "capture" and "bubble" phases for keyboard events like in JavaScript?
In GUI development, there are typically two different behaviors for handling global shortcut keys:

High-priority global shortcuts: These shortcuts take precedence over all other input. If a global shortcut is triggered, it immediately handles the event and prevents any other components from receiving it.

Low-priority global shortcuts: These shortcuts only trigger if no other component has captured the event. If another component consumes the event, the global shortcut is ignored, unless the event is propagated (bubbled) back up.


In JavaScript:
In web development, JavaScript handles events in two phases: the "capturing" phase and the "bubbling" phase. To achieve the two shortcut behaviors:

For high-priority, we can bind the global shortcut in the capturing phase (call document.addEventListener with capture: true).
For low-priority, we bind the shortcut in the bubbling phase (call document.addEventListener with capture: false).

My question for Flutter:
It seems that there is only bubbling in Flutter? How can I achieve both solutions at the same time?
